# magento 2 copy orders via database

Tags: magento-2.1, sales-order

I have a magento 2.1 shop with order I want to move to a different magento 2.1 store via DB.  Is it as easy as moving the sales_ tables?  Do I need them all?  Do I need other tables?

```
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_daily
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_monthly
sales_bestsellers_aggregated_yearly
sales_creditmemo
sales_creditmemo_comment
sales_creditmemo_grid
sales_creditmemo_item
sales_invoice
sales_invoiced_aggregated
sales_invoiced_aggregated_order
sales_invoice_comment
sales_invoice_grid
sales_invoice_item
sales_order
sales_order_address
sales_order_aggregated_created
sales_order_aggregated_updated
sales_order_grid
sales_order_item
sales_order_payment
sales_order_status
sales_order_status_history
sales_order_status_label
sales_order_status_state
sales_order_tax
sales_order_tax_item
sales_payment_transaction
sales_refunded_aggregated
sales_refunded_aggregated_order
sales_sequence_meta
sales_sequence_profile
sales_shipment
sales_shipment_comment
sales_shipment_grid
sales_shipment_item
sales_shipment_track
sales_shipping_aggregated
sales_shipping_aggregated_order
```